# How to split a string into an array at a given character (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var stringToSplit = "10000.9409.13924.11025.10000._.11025.13225._.9801.12321.12321.11664.";

//Finished result should be:
result == ["10000.", "9409.", "13924.", "11025.", "10000.", "_.", "11025.", "13225.", "_.", "9801.", "12321.", "12321.", "11664."]
```

After each "." I want to split it and push it into an array.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You split it, and map over. With every iteration you add an . to the end

```js
var stringToSplit = "10000.9409.13924.11025.10000._.11025.13225._.9801.12321.12321.11664.";

let result = stringToSplit.split(".").map(el => el + ".");

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could match the parts, instead of using split.

```js
var string = "10000.9409.13924.11025.10000._.11025.13225._.9801.12321.12321.11664.",
    result = string.match(/[^.]+\./g);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var stringToSplit = "10000.9409.13924.11025.10000._.11025.13225._.9801.12321.12321.11664.";

var arr = stringToSplit.split(".").map(item => item+".");

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

split the string using `.` delimiter and then slice to remove the last empty space. Then use `map` to return the required array of elements

```js
var stringToSplit = "10000.9409.13924.11025.10000._.11025.13225._.9801.12321.12321.11664.";
let newData = stringToSplit.split('.');
let val = newData.slice(0, newData.length - 1).map(item => `${item}.`)
console.log(val)
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use a `lookbehind` with `.split`

```js
var stringToSplit = "10000.9409.13924.11025.10000._.11025.13225._.9801.12321.12321.11664.";
let out = stringToSplit.split(/(?<=\.)/);
console.log(out)
```